# WebTestClient All negative unit test cases passed

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webflux, webtestclient

I am trying to write unit tests using **WebTestClient** in my Spring boot application.
But when tried to run, all controller test cases passed including some negative test cases.

Below is my MainApplication, Controller and ControllerTest code for your reference:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}



@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@WebFluxTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyControllerTests {

   @MockBean
   MyService service;

   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient webTestClient;


   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception {

       webTestClient
               .get()
               .uri(uriBuilder ->
                       uriBuilder
                              .path("/my-controller/test")
                               .build())
               .exchange()
               .expectBody(String.class)
               .equals("Hii");
   }
}



@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/my-controller")
public class MyController {
    private final MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        return "Hello :)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually asserting whether the the response body is equal or not. Try something like this:

```
boolean result = webTestClient
    .get()
    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/my-controller/test").build())
    .exchange()
    .expectBody(String.class)
    .equals("Hii");
Assertions.assertFalse(result); // this should pass
```